# JumpLoader ClassNotFoundException Error?

Tags: java

My JumpLoader was working on my site for a while, but I got a couple messages from clients saying there was an error recently. Not sure if it is from and update or something but I confirmed it is not working.

The error on the applet says `Error. Click for details`. If I click it, it says `ClassNotFoundException` and below it the `jmaster.jumploader.app.JumpLoaderApplet.class`.

Here is my code:

```
  <applet name="jumpLoaderApplet" id="jumpLoaderApplet"
        codebase="/java"
        code="jmaster.jumploader.app.JumpLoaderApplet.class"
        width="600"
        archive="/java/jumploader_z.jar"
        height="400"
        mayscript>
     <param name="uc_uploadUrl" value="/my/server/location/">
     <param name="uc_maxFileLength" value="3145728"/> <!--2mb = 2097152, 1 megabyte = 1048576 bytes, 3mb = 3145728)-->
     <param name="uc_addImagesOnly" value="true"/>
     <param name="uc_maxFiles" value="200"/>
     <param name="ac_fireUploaderStatusChanged" value="true"/>
     <!--<param name="uc_minFiles" value="5"/> -->
  </applet>
```

I tried with and without the codebase attribute (i know it's optional).

Anyone have any thoughts? I just downloaded the latest versions of all the jumploader files and uploaded to my server, same issue. I tried the demo on the JL website and it does work fine (tells me it is not my browser).

Thanks in advance. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I'd try to remove the trailing `.class` from the `code` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, that's not it.  They say to do that in the documentation.  Thanks for the suggestion though!  http://jumploader.com/demo_embedded.html